# Code is showing SyntaxError in IDLE 2.7.11, but seems to work on Canopy 1.5.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy

I'm relatively new to Python and I am experiencing some problems with trying to understand an error that keeps occurring with a code I have written.

My code is as follows (the code is to find the perfect cube number):

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter number: '))
ans = 0
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
if ans**3 != abs(x):
    print 'not cube number'
else:
    print x, 'is a cube of', ans
```

All is well until I reach line 5. After I write line 5 (`if ans**3 != abs(x):`) and I press enter, I get an error saying: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I execute this in IDLE (version 2.7.11). But the full code once fully executed works perfectly fine on Canopy (version 1.5.2). I can't seem to find what on earth the syntax error could possibly be! It's driving me mad!

Could this be a problem with IDLE just not, by any chance, being compatible with my laptop? (I am using a Macbook pro version 10.10.4).

I should also add: on IDLE, when I type the code this way (obviously wrong but still just to see):

```
if ans**3 != abs(x):
ans = 0
while ans**3 < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
    if ans**3 != abs(x):
        print 'not cube number'
    else:
        print x, 'is a cube of', and
```

I get the following result (with an integer input of 27):

```
27 not a cube number
27 not a cube number
27 cube number of 3
```

So it seems to be running through the `while` loop body fine, it just isn't accepting the indentation!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. This code doesn't have any syntax errors.

Comment: The code & statement is syntactically correct.

Comment: It's being accepted by Canopy, not by IDLE! :(

Comment: On IDLE, when I enter the 5th line of code without any indentation to it, and I try to go onto the indented line 6, at that point it raises this error message. It is indeed frustrating!

Comment: Tangentially .. what functionality are you getting from IDLE that you don't get from Canopy? Why are you using a very old version of Canopy? The current version is 1.7.4, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website